# Why does TIOCSTI injection disable stty echo in bash when used with bind?

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to bind a key in bash to inject commands into the terminal using TIOCSTI ([example here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217390/54030)). This works just fine until I inject certain commands. The end goal is a bash reverse search (ctrl-r) replacement, but this serves as an example to show my issue.

```
# Test using a clean environment
env -i bash --noprofile --norc

# Define TIOCSTI helper
function inject() {   perl -e 'ioctl(STDIN, 0x5412, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV' "$@"; }

# Bind ctrl-b to inject 'yes | less' as a test
bind -x '"\C-b":"inject yes \| less"'

<press ctrl-b>yes | less<press enter>
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
y  (press RETURN)
y
...
<press q to exit less>

# Terminal is now foobared. In particular I can't see what I type. Why?

# Enable echo
stty echo
```

If I just enter `inject yes \| less` and press enter the terminal is fine afterwards. I think it has something to do with TIOCSTI being run within bash's `bind`. Injecting `yes | less`, just `yes` and a long `git log` trigger this but many others such as `echo` and `vi` do not. Interestingly I can ctrl-b to inject the command, delete everything on the line, retype it myself and I still lose echo. It's as though readline gets poisoned with some invisible character that I can't delete.

Why am I losing echo?

How can I fix it? E.g. perhaps some more codes need to be sent with TIOCSTI to make it safe.

`GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Why did you choose this rather complicated solution rather than just defining C-b to be a keyboard macro? (`bind 'Control-b: "yes | less"'`)

Comment: @rici This is pretty close. I'm trying to simulate Ctrl-R where I can run my own program to either replace the current line or both replace it and then execute it as though I'd hit enter. Setting `READLINE_LINE` works for the former but not latter. Binding `$( select_from_history )` with `-x` almost works except doesn't open the ncurses screen. Inserting and running `select_from_history` directly also works but then I'm left with the command cluttering my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need some sort of keyboard macro, you could place something like this (as example) in your ~/.inputrc :

```
# F12 has a keyboard macro:
"\e[24~": "cls; (date; make 2>&1 || flash 1 >/dev/console 2>&1; date) | tee make.res^M"
```

Note 1: The ^M is an actual control-M character (i.e. a \r, CR, Carriage Return).

Note 2: I think '.inputrc' is picky about spacing; I seem to recal there has to be exactly one space between the key and the macrodef.

Note 3: To see what your F12 (for example) outputs, run `cat` and press the F12 key and take note of the string it prints.

I used to have this for years when bells and whistles were en vogue, and I compiled every last damn package myself and just kept all `make` logs (cls is a script that basically does `tput clear`, flash was a homegrown script to flash the terminal and ring a bell :)

End note: macros like the above that contain a CR at the end make me nervous and I (now) consider dangerous. Just the macro placing the command after the prompt, waiting for your interactive CR (or ^C) looks to me the safer way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is [a bug in bash](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?h=devel&id=b6a567e7f13406952cbb1d1adb2f00b2260a871e), and it is not triggered by specifically the TIOCSTI injection, but by running a program in the `bind -x` handler (in this case: `perl`).

Your example still results in the described bug behavior in `GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, but in the version built from the `devel` branch (`GNU bash, version 5.2.0(1)-alpha (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`), which contains a fix, everything works as expected.